# TFS 2012 - Developers can not create folders under projects

Tags: directory

How do I give my developers (Contributors group) permissions to add folders to a project?

Comment: Do they have permissions to checkout/checkin and are they able to do that?

Comment: They do have permissions to checkout and in...

Comment: Server or local workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, if a person has check-in/checkout permission then he will be able to add new files/folders to TFS. Now has your developers created a workspace and mapped the server files/folders to their local machine? You can only add files and create folders if you have configured your workspace.